# real, protected, virtual mode memory addressing

Tags: memory, memory-management

there are these three types of addressing the memory. I am reading [this](http://fetweb.ju.edu.jo/staff/ee/mhawa/331/Protected.pdf) brief explanation of these concepts related to Intel® Pentium 4, but would be very thankful if someone could clarify things a little.

> In real-mode, only the first 1M bytes of memory can be addressed with
>   the typical segment:offset logical address. Each segment is 64K bytes
>   long

but

> In the protected-mode, memory larger than 1MB can be accessed

what are the main differences and advantages of each one? why i.e. windows xp uses protected mode?
and to what protection does this "protected" refer?